# Why the time to execute a method in GPU is more compare to in CPU in hybridizer projects?

Tags: c#, gpu, hybridizer

I am running the Hello World example of hybridizer-basic-samples.But the time taking for the execution is more in GPU than Cpu.

```
    [EntryPoint("run")]
    public static void Run(int N, double[] a, double[] b)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, N, i => { a[i] += b[i]; });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = 1024 * 1024 * 16;
        double[] acuda = new double[N];
        double[] adotnet = new double[N];
        double[] b = new double[N];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            acuda[i] = rand.NextDouble();
            adotnet[i] = acuda[i];
            b[i] = rand.NextDouble();
        }

        cudaDeviceProp prop;
        cuda.GetDeviceProperties(out prop, 0);
        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda().SetDistrib(prop.multiProcessorCount * 16, 128);
        dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());

        // run the method on GPU
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        wrapped.Run(N, acuda, b);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

        // run .Net method
        var watch2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Run(N, adotnet, b);
        watch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
```

When i run the program, the execution time of the Run() in GPU is always more than the .Net method.Like for the GPU execution it took 818ms but for the cpu,89ms.Can any one please explain me the reason?

Comment: Do a warmup run before benchmarking to make sure you are not benchmarking the jitter. Also make sure you are benchmarking in release mode with no debugger attached. Once you do both of those things, see if results vary.

Comment: To make things worse, you are benchmarking a dynamic call's first invokation (`wrapped.Run`) so you are essentially benchmarking the runtime compiler starting up and resolving the dynamic call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @InBetween, it is likely that you are measuring compiler overhead. It is good practice to do a warmup pass to let all code compile first. Or use something like [benchmarking.net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) that does that for you.

Another possible reason is overhead. When running things on a GPU the system would need to copy the input data to GPU memory, and copy the result back again. There will probably also be other costs involved. Adding numbers together is a very simple operation, so it is likely the processor can run at max theoretical speed.

Lets do some back of the envelope calculations. Assume the CPU can do 4 adds per clock (i.e. what AVX256 can do). 4 * 8 bytes per double = 32 bytes per clock, and 4*10^9 clocks per second. This gives 128 GB/s in processing speed. This is significantly higher than the PCIe 3 x16 bandwith of 16GB/s. You will probably not reach this speed due to other limitations, but it shows that the limiting factor is probably not the processor itself, so using a GPU will probably not improve things.

GPU processing should show better gains when using more complicated algorithms that do more processing for each data-item.